# Navbar links don't center properly

Tags: html, css, navbar

I made a simple webpage with header and navbar, but I came across this little problem that's actually pretty annoying. The links aren't 100% in the middle of the inline list, here's a screenshot:
https://i.gyazo.com/105d8156e667277d0b31f18ba6a3b7db.png

To prevent confusion, the whole page is centered, but the screenshot is just of the navbar part.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test website</h1>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS file:

```
/* navigation bar */
#nav {
    width: 490px;
    margin: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/* unordered list in navbar */
#nav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

/* list items in navbar */
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* links in items of navbar */
#nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* header 1 */
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the default padding that is being applied to the `ul`, simply zero out the padding:

```
#nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3f8ccks6/)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `padding` and `margin` from the UL:

```
#nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct, but in ideal scenario `<a>` should have padding so in future if we want to have a background-color for link, it will occupied entire block.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lu5qjux/